# Layer was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was trying to build my own model following this [blog](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/07/multi-label-classification-with-keras/), adapting it to a 2-input-and-2-output model.
However when I tried to build the model using Keras Functional API (using tensorflow backend)

```
inputV = Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding="same",input_shape = (96,96,3),name='Input of Visible Task')
inputH = Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding="same",input_shape = (96,96,3),name='Input of Hidden Task')

hiddenLayer = Activation("relu")
outputV = hiddenLayer(inputV)
outputH = hiddenLayer(inputH)
```

Error raises as

```
Layer activation_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D'>. Full input: [<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x000001CF1211D6D8>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

However when I tried

```
inputV = Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding="same",input_shape = (96,96,3)
                activation='relu',name='Input of Visible Task')
```

everything is OK.
Why it doesn't work when i try to *Activate* separately?

Comment: You are completely missing Input layer to start the layer chain, it will not work without that

Answer (score 0):

The Keras functional API works by chaining the input flow, eg.:

```
inp = Input(shape=(...))
x = Conv2D(...)(inp)
x = Activation(...)(x)
x = Conv2D(...)(x)
mymodel = Model(inp, x)
```

This obviously won't run, but can you see how I'm chaining the `x` variable from output, to next layer's input? Keras will trace this flow, when constructing the model.

Now, in your code there are several problems.
1. Using the functional API your model should start with tf.keras.Input()!
2. You are missing the chaining of the data. 
3. You are missing the model construction part (the `mymodel` part)